# Is Android hotword detection possible with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, detection, speech, hotword

I am building this app that needs to be voice-based for 90% of the funtionalities to work, hence the UI is basically negligible. I have managed to get [Speech To Text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) working but I want to know if this application can be made active using hotword detection.

Answer (score 1):

Picovoice's Porcupine has [Flutter support](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine#flutter) out of the box.